# How do I turn certain rows in a csv column into a JSON format?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have certain rows in a child column formatted like this

> { "label ":  "Apple",  "id ": 2,  "dataType ":  "Fruit "}]

The issue I have is that since the child column is empty in couple of rows, but gets populated like this in some other rows, I wanted to see if I could turn this into a JSON object and see if I can do operations like that, but that doesn't seem possible as I keep getting an error saying

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I think that is because the "id ": 2, there is no "2" in the 2. How can I replace an empty value like that 2 and turn it into "2", so it is a proper JSON format?

Also is it possible for me to like maybe extract the label, id, and dataType and make them their own heading on a different exported csv file? for example, let's say my input .csv file is like this

> **Value, Children:**
> 1,"label ":  "Banana",  "id ": 11, "dataType ":  "Fruits "
> 2,
> 3, "label ":  "Shoes  ",  "id ": 1150,
> "dataType ":  "Accesories "

I want the outputted file to look like this:

> **label, id, dataType,**
>
> Banana, 11,  Fruits
>
> Shoes, 1150, Accesories

Is this possible?

EDIT: The original dataset actually contains multiple values of

> {"label": "val1", "id":2, "dataType": "value", "label": "val2", "id":3, "dataType": "value3"}

in the same row, inside of one cell there can be multiple of this values defined, can I still make them into column headings and store values in the associated column's?

Comment: `{ "label ": "Apple", "id ": 2, "dataType ": "Fruit "}]` is invalid. Please provide a sample of df properly.

Comment: The data provided for `input.csv` yields a dataframe of shape (3, 3). This is probably not what you want. Please revise this. My answer below is based on the assumption that every row contains a single cell with a dictionary (i.e. `{}`) as you wrote at the beginning of your post.

Answer (score 1):

Say your column is:

```
column = pd.Series(
    [{"label ": "Banana", "id ": 11, "dataType ": "Fruits "},
     {},
     {"label ": "Shoes ", "id ": 1150, "dataType ": "Accesories "}]
)
```

You can convert this column to a dataframe by `pd.json_normalize`:

```
new_df = pd.json_normalize(column)
```

And then save it in the format you like (e.g., csv):

```
new_df.to_csv('file_name.csv', index=False)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I just made some changes, in some of the rows there are multiple "label's and "id"'s  in that same row, can this script work in that case?